# When trying to create a splunk machine I keep receiving the same error

Tags: dpkg

I created a VM in VB and then downloaded Splunk from their website.

Then put in this command:
`sudo dpkg -i /home/siem/Downloads/splunk-7.3.8-bdc98854fc40-linux-2.6-amd64.deb`

But keep receiving this Error:

```
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /home/siem/Downloads/splunk-7.3.8-bdc98854fc40-linux-2.6-amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/splunk/bin/jars/thirdparty/aws/aws-java-sdk-1.10.8.jar' to '/opt/splunk/bin/jars/thirdparty/aws/aws-java-sdk-1.10.8.jar.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Comment: Thank you for editing. It looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

"`compressed data is corrupt`" means that the downloaded file isn't correct. Download it again.

Check the site for a file with the same name, but a `.md5` or `.gpg` addition. The additional small file will let you perform a "checksum" on the big file.